# Cannot execute dataset with runtime parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are creating some pipelines in Azure Datafactory V2 and want to re-use as much as we can the elements. Currently we are facing a problem with pipelines that use a dataset with runtime parameters. The error message we are having is:

- The template validation failed: 'the string character 'P' at position '41' is not expected..'

We followed the directives from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#examples) but is still throws the error.
Below you will find the pipeline and dataset jsons:

```
Dataset:

    {
    "name": "DS-PARAM",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "LS-ADLS",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreFile",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": {
                "value": "@dataset().file",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "folderPath": {
                "value": "@dataset().directory",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "directory": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "file": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    }}
    

Pipeline:
    {
        "name": "pipeline2",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Copy1",
                    "type": "Copy",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "policy": {
                        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                        "retry": 0,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 20
                    },
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSource",
                            "recursive": true
                        },
                        "sink": {
                            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
                        },
                        "enableStaging": false,
                        "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
                    },
                    "inputs": [
                        {
                            "referenceName": "DS-PARAM",
                            "type": "DatasetReference",
                            "parameters": {
                                "directory": "/",
                                "file": "readme.txt"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "outputs": [
                        {
                            "referenceName": "DS-PARAM",
                            "type": "DatasetReference",
                            "parameters": {
                                "directory": "/",
                                "file": "readme2.txt"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The linked service is for a Datalake Store. We have tried the same code with an ARM template and also by building the Dataset and Pipeline from the new interface MS released on 16.01.2018.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution: Remove all dashes from the dataset name.**

I spent all day trying to solve the exact same problem and it drove me absolutely crazy. The good news is I figured out what was causing the problem. The bad news is we're going to have to adopt a different naming convention until the Azure team fixes the problem. I sent them my observations through the feedback option.

The unexpected character about which it complains is always the character immediately after the first dash. So call your dataset DSPARAM or dsParam or anything that contains only letters. I haven't tried with underscores and digits.

Regards

Comment: Another thing I noticed through the UI is that after you make any change on these elements the json that you have inserted on advance is removed. Nice catch on this!

Comment: @g_brahimaj Could you elaborate? What kind of change on which elements? You do have to publish your changes for them to stick.

Comment: After I changed the name of the dataset, the declaration of the parameters that I had put in the advanced tab was removed.

Comment: @g_brahimaj You can add/remove/update dataset parameters under the 'Parameters' tab. There is a 'Create/update parameters' section. There is  no need to use the 'Advanced' tab for this. Although what you are describing is disturbing. I didn't loose anything by renaming but I hadn't used the 'Advanced' tab.

Comment: Thought I share some more details: it appears that using underscores is perfectly fine. Might be a good alternative to dashes.

Comment: Don't use digits as well, also for Dataset naming!

Comment: @Woodcarver - I'm experiencing the same issue which has recently started. My blob container is called `mihndbot-transcripts` and I have the exact same error. The container has always had this name and this hasn't been an issue before for me - did you ever get a response from the Azure team when you fed back on this?

Comment: @Sean I don't know about blob container names with dashes. I've never had a dash in the name of a container that I used in ADF. My issue was with datasets. I never directly contacted support about this. I recall sending feedback through the feedback feature and they don't usually reply those. Sometimes they do, but mostly they don't. I am surprised to hear about such a problem so late in the game. Good luck!